# Ionic upload video to server

Tags: ionic-framework, video-capture

I am trying to send a video to server but I get nothing on return.

Here is the code:

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions()
  options = {
      fileKey:      "avatar",
      fileName:     $scope.video.name,
      mimeType:     $scope.video.type,
      chunkedMode:  false,
  };

 $cordovaFileTransfer.upload(serverURL, $scope.video.fullPath, options).then(function(result) {
            console.log("SUCCESS: " + JSON.stringify(result.response));
        }, function(err) {
            console.log("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(err));
        }, function (progress) {
            console.log("PROGRESS: " + JSON.stringify(progress));
        });

    }
```

For your information, I am recording a video using `cordovaCapture.captureVideo` plugin and the return is stored in `$scope.video`

By the way, here is the log of `$scope.video`

```
{"name":"20170712_184203.mp4","localURL":"cdvfile://localhost/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/20170712_184203.mp4","type":"video/mp4","lastModified":null,"lastModifiedDate":1499895726000,"size":3926733,"start":0,"end":0,"fullPath":"file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20170712_184203.mp4"}
```

and the return is

```
ERROR: {"code":null,"source":null,"target":null,"http_status":null,"body":null,"exception":null}
```

Thanks